# Reference to session attrribute not getting null despite explicitly setting it to null

Tags: java, httpsession

I have an object stored in session. In my controller, when a user sends a request, it concurrently executes the following code :

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject) req.getSession().getAttribute("myObject");
while(!obj.isNewResultAvailable()){
    //will loop until new result is available.
}
```

As I noted, it executes concurrently, so while the controll is still inside the loop, the user can do some other things, such as, when the user presses another button, a request will be sent to a controller that does the following :

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject) req.getSession().getAttribute("myObject");
obj = null;
```

My expectation is that, the code that loops until a new result is available will throw a `NullPointerException`. Only to find our that its not.

So, why is the object pulled from the session in another controller is not `null` despite setting that object to another controller as `null`?

**Edit :**

In my current code, I actually tried doing

`req.getSession().setAttribute("myObject", null);`

and

`req.getSession().removeAttribute("myObject");`

still, that did not solve my problem, the object in the while loop is still not nulled.

**Realization**

For those who will get to this kind of confusion, the root of my problem is **I got confused how objects are passed in Java**. My problem is as simple as, `obj = null` is just setting the **reference** of `obj` to null and **NOT** the object itself.

As pointed by morgano, the object in the session has been referenced locally by the thread that executes the while loop, so, `req.getSession().setAttribute("myObject", null);` and `req.getSession().removeAttribute("myObject");` will not result to the object getting nulled. These are just basically removing the references of to the object from the session (thus ideally making it a candidate for gc, which will not happen in my situation since the object is referenced localy by a long running http request [the while loop thing]).

Comment: Can you post some of your concurrent controllers code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that, do this:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("myObject", null);
```

or much better:

```
req.getSession().removeAttribute("myObject");
```

what you are doing is set to null a reference to an object, you are not modifying the session attributes at all.

UPDATE AFTER QUESTION'S EDITION:

Once the "iterating" thread has a reference to your object, it is futile for the "deleting" thread to remove it from the session, your object has been referenced by a local variable in the first thread.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
MyObject a = new MyObject();
MyObject b = a;
b = null;
```

What you seem to be expecting is:

```
MyObject a = new MyObject(); // a is the new object
MyObject b = a; // b is the same object
b = null; // set the object referenced by both a and b to null
```

What really happens:

```
MyObject a = new MyObject(); // a is the new object
MyObject b = a; // b points to the same object as a
b = null; // b doesn't point to anything
```

So in short: instead of setting the **referenced value** to null (i.e. the session in your example), you're actually setting the **reference itself** to null (i.e. `obj` in your example).

Comment: My question is in Java. Can you update your answer with Java context?

Comment: Done. It's essentially identical other than the MyObject bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. Session is a key value map. You have to set null explicitly against particular key value.

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("myObject", null);
```

or remove the key at all.

```
req.getSession().removeAttribute("myObject");
```

Comment: I did that, still, object is not getting nulled